# How do I create a winner in a game of BlackJack?

Tags: c#, .net, blackjack

In my c# we are building a blackjack game with classes. I have card.cs
hand.cs and deck.cs which I'm posting with this. I am trying to put the game together and I cannot figure out the getWinner() method or how to code and show a winner. My code for my hand looks correct as far as I can tell- except when I first run the game it does not add and show the total of the two cards so I am starting there, then working on the winner- Can I create a winner in the Hand class? I was thinking it would be better on the Form.cs?

```
 class Hand
{
    private List<Card> listOfCards = new List<Card>();

    public int cardCount()
    {
        return listOfCards.Count();
    }

    public void addCard(Card card)
    {
        listOfCards.Add(card);
    }
    private void clearHand()
    {
        listOfCards.Clear();
    }
    public Card getCardAtIndex(int index)
    {
        Card card = new Card();
        if(index < listOfCards.Count)
        {
            card = listOfCards[index];
        }
        return card;
    }
    public int getAllCardsTotal()
    {
        int total = 0;
        int aceCount = 0;

        foreach(Card card in listOfCards)
        {
            if (card.getBlackJackValue() == 1)
                aceCount++;

            total = total + card.getBlackJackValue();
        }
        //See if we need to use the Ace as a 1 or 11
        if(aceCount > 0)
        {
            //Dealer stays 17-21 or can be player
            if (total >= 7 && total <= 11)
                total = total + 10;
        }
        return total;
    }
   
}
```

}

```
 class Deck
{
    private List<Card> listOfCards = new List<Card>();

    public Deck()
    {
        listOfCards.Clear();
        loadDeck();
    }
    public int cardCount()
    {
        return listOfCards.Count();
    }
   
    public Card drawCard()
    {
        Card card = new Card();

        //get random card from deck
        int cardCount = listOfCards.Count;

        Random random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        int cardIndex = random.Next(0, cardCount);

        card = listOfCards[cardIndex]; //Get a copy of the card
        listOfCards.RemoveAt(cardIndex); // This removes the card

        return card;
    }
    private void loadDeck()
    {
        //load in order A-KClubs- Diamonds - Hearts - Spades
        int imageIndex = 0;
        for(int rank = 1; rank <=13; rank++)
        {
            Card card = new Card(rank, Card.SuitType.Clubs, imageIndex);
            listOfCards.Add(card);
            imageIndex++; //increment each time we add a card

            card = new Card(rank, Card.SuitType.Diamonds, imageIndex);
            listOfCards.Add(card);
            imageIndex++; //increment each time we add a card

            card = new Card(rank, Card.SuitType.Hearts, imageIndex);
            listOfCards.Add(card);
            imageIndex++; //increment each time we add a card

            card = new Card(rank, Card.SuitType.Spades, imageIndex);
            listOfCards.Add(card);
            imageIndex++; //increment each time we add a card
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
class Card
{
    public enum SuitType { Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades}

    private int rank;
    private SuitType suit;
    private int blackJackValue;
    private int imageIndex;

    
    public SuitType Suit { get => suit; set => suit = value; }
    public int ImageIndex { get => imageIndex; set => imageIndex = value; }
    

    public Card(int rank, SuitType suit, int blackJackValue, int imageIndex)
    {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
        this.imageIndex = imageIndex;
    }
    public Card()
    {

    }
    public Card(int rank, SuitType suit, int imageIndex)
    {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.Suit = suit;
        this.ImageIndex = imageIndex;
    }
    public int getBlackJackValue()
    {
        int blackJackValue = 0;

        if (rank > 9)
            blackJackValue = 10;
        
        else
            blackJackValue = rank;

        return blackJackValue;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        String cardName = "";
        string cardRank = "";
        //Display a string of ace of clubs or 3 of diamonds
        if (rank == 13)
            cardRank = "King";
        else if (rank == 12)
            cardRank = "Queen";
        else if (rank == 11)
            cardRank = "Jack";
        else if (rank == 1)
            cardRank = "Ace";

        cardName = cardRank + "of" + suit.ToString();
        return cardName;
    }
}
```

}

And the form1.cs so far is:

```
public partial class BlackJack : Form
{
    public BlackJack()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Global variables
    Deck gameDeck = new Deck();
    Hand playerHand = new Hand();
    Hand dealerHand = new Hand();

    //To increment the games?
    int playerWins = 0;
    int dealerWins = 0;
    int ties = 0;
    int totalGames = 0;

    List<PictureBox> listPBPlayer = new List<PictureBox>();
    List<PictureBox> listPBDealer = new List<PictureBox>();


    private void BlackJack_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dealHands();
        addPictureBoxesToLists();

    }


    private void dealHands()
    {
        gameDeck = new Deck();
        playerHand = new Hand();
        dealerHand = new Hand();

        hidePictureBoxes();
        Card card = new Card();

        //Add players first card
        card = gameDeck.drawCard();
        playerHand.addCard(card);
        pictureBoxP1.Image = imageListCards.Images[card.ImageIndex];
        pictureBoxP1.Visible = true;

        //Add dealers first card
        card = gameDeck.drawCard();
        dealerHand.addCard(card);
        pictureBoxD1.Image = imageListCards.Images[card.ImageIndex];
        pictureBoxD1.Visible = true;

        //Add players 2nd card
        card = gameDeck.drawCard();
        dealerHand.addCard(card);
        pictureBoxP2.Image = imageListCards.Images[card.ImageIndex];
        pictureBoxP2.Visible = true;

        //Add dealers 2nd card
        card = gameDeck.drawCard();
        dealerHand.addCard(card);
        pictureBoxD2.Image = imageListCards.Images[52]; // card face back image

        labelPlayerTotal.Text = playerHand.getAllCardsTotal().ToString();
        labelDealerWins.Text = dealerHand.getCardAtIndex(0).getBlackJackValue().ToString();
        labelWhoWon.Text = "";

        buttonDEAL.Enabled = true; 
        buttonHIT.Enabled = true;
        buttonSTAND.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void addPictureBoxesToLists()
    {
        listPBPlayer.Clear();
        listPBPlayer.Add(pictureBoxP1);
        listPBPlayer.Add(pictureBoxP2);
        listPBPlayer.Add(pictureBoxP3);
        listPBPlayer.Add(pictureBoxP4);
        listPBPlayer.Add(pictureBoxP5);
        listPBPlayer.Add(pictureBoxP6);
        listPBPlayer.Add(pictureBoxP7);

        listPBDealer.Clear();
        listPBDealer.Add(pictureBoxD1);
        listPBDealer.Add(pictureBoxD2);
        listPBDealer.Add(pictureBoxD3);
        listPBDealer.Add(pictureBoxD4);
        listPBDealer.Add(pictureBoxD5);
        listPBDealer.Add(pictureBoxD6);
        listPBDealer.Add(pictureBoxD7);
    }

    private void newRound()
    {
        dealHands();
    }
    private void hidePictureBoxes()
    {
        listPBPlayer.Clear();
        listPBDealer.Clear();

        foreach (PictureBox pb in listPBPlayer)
        {
            //pb.Image = imageListCards.Images[52];
            pb.Visible = false;
        }
        foreach (PictureBox pb in listPBDealer)
        {
            //pb.Image = imageListCards.Images[52]; - never got to see all the cards on the screen? 
            pb.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void buttonDEAL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dealHands();
    }

    private void buttonHIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Card card = new Card();
        card = gameDeck.drawCard();
        playerHand.addCard(card);
       // textBoxPlayerTotal.Text = playerHand.getAllCardsTotal.ToString();

        //Show the new card
        listPBPlayer[playerHand.cardCount() - 1].Image = imageListCards.Images[card.ImageIndex];
        listPBDealer[playerHand.cardCount() - 1].Visible = true;

        if (playerHand.getAllCardsTotal() > 21)
        {
            //Busted show the dealer cards and display second card
            listPBDealer[1].Image = imageListCards.Images[dealerHand.getCardAtIndex(1).ImageIndex];
            listPBDealer[1].Visible = true;

           // textBoxDealerTotal.Text = dealerHand.getHandCardTotal.ToString();
           // textBoxWhoWon.Text = getWinner();

            buttonDEAL.Enabled = true;
            buttonHIT.Enabled = false;
            buttonSTAND.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void buttonSTAND_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Stand - have the dealer try to bust
    }
    private void getWinner()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: this belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Side note: usually Ace in Black Jack can have *two* values: either `11` or `1`, and so `A + A + 7 + 2` is a Black Jack (`21`), not burst. That's why I doubt if just single integer property - `private int blackJackValue;` is a good solution

Comment: I see what you are saying- thankyou.